# The Page Has Expired Due To Inactivity. Please Refresh And Try Again. laravel 5.6 using auth of laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

laravel version: 5.6 (latest) php version: 7.1.14 System: Linux Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler

My problem is that when I run the app in localhost it works fine but when I uploaded this on server Homepage works fine but when I try to login in or try to sign up it shows error:

```
"The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again"
```

When i just deleted the views folder inside
*/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/* then i'm getting this:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php204
>   44 Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler prepareException
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php176
>   43 Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler render
>   …/app/Exceptions/Handler.php51 42 App\Exceptions\Handler render
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php83 41
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline handleException
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php55 40
>   Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php70
>   39 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 38
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 37
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php49
>   36 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 35
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 34
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php63
>   33 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 32
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 31
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php37
>   30 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 29
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 28
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php59
>   27 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 26
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 25
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php102 24
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline then
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php661 23
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router runRouteWithinStack
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php636 22
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router runRoute
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php602 21
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php591 20
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php176
>   19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php30 18
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php57 17
>   Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 16
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 15
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php30
>   14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 13
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 12
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php30
>   11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 10
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 9
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php27
>   8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 7
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 6
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php46
>   5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php149 4
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 3
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php102 2
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline then
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php151
>   1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel sendRequestThroughRouter
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php116

**My blade Code:**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Login') }}
        </button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
            {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

How to fix this?
I also tried all the previous question suggestion.
I have also see that its it as `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null)`,
and nothin in .env like session_domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the csrf_filed to your form.
add this just after your opening form tag.

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Edit:
in laravel 5.6 you can just do `@csrf` after the form tag.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden **CSRF token field** in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `csrf_field` helper to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

With **Laravel 5.6 and higher version** using Blades templates, it's pretty easy.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

**NOTE:** It doesn't work, then Refresh the browser cache and now it might work